# i am trying to insall apache qpid getting the following error while doing make

Tags: c++, messagebroker, qpid

i am trying to install apache qpid by svn checkout,i have installed all the tools while doing make i got the error

svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/qpid/trunk

```
qpid/sys/SocketTransport.cpp:209: error: ‘a2’ is used uninitialized in this function
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_cc.hpp:83: note: ‘a2’ was declared here
qpid/sys/SocketTransport.cpp:209: error: ‘a2’ may be used uninitialized in this function
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:551: note: ‘a2’ was declared here
qpid/sys/SocketTransport.cpp:209: error: ‘a2’ may be used uninitialized in this function
/usr/include/boost/bind/storage.hpp:276: note: ‘a2’ was declared here
qpid/sys/SocketTransport.cpp:209: error: ‘a2’ may be used uninitialized in this function
/usr/include/boost/bind/storage.hpp:227: note: ‘a2’ was declared here
qpid/sys/SocketTransport.cpp:209: error: ‘a2’ may be used uninitialized in this function
/usr/include/boost/bind/storage.hpp:195: note: ‘a2’ was declared here
qpid/sys/SocketTransport.cpp:209: error: ‘a2’ may be used uninitialized in this function
/usr/include/boost/bind/storage.hpp:129: note: ‘a2’ was declared here
make[3]: *** [qpid/sys/libqpidbroker_la-SocketTransport.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nimbus/Downloads/svn/trunk/qpid/cpp/src'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nimbus/Downloads/svn/trunk/qpid/cpp/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nimbus/Downloads/svn/trunk/qpid/cpp/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```